# Flutter iOS Error when adding Firestore dependency

Tags: ios, visual-studio-code, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm having issues trying to add cloud_firestore dependence to any project I create. I've created fresh project which builds and runs in iOS (I haven't installed an android simulator yet). But when I add the cloud_firestore dependency line into the pubspec.yaml, get the dependency, and then try and build, I get the following error:

> Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
> Xcode build done.                                            2.3s
> Failed to build iOS app
> Error output from Xcode build:
> ↳
> ** BUILD FAILED **
> Xcode's output:
> ↳
> /Flutter/hello_world/hello_world/ios/Pods/leveldb-library/table/block.cc:13:10: 
> fatal error: 'util/coding.h' file not found
> #include "util/coding.h"
> ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> 1 error generated.
> Could not build the application for the simulator.

#### My pubspec.xaml file:

```
name: hello_world
description: A new Flutter project.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.0.0-dev.68.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cloud_firestore: 

  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2


dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
```